# Chrome 94 DevTools crashes when doing memory profiling

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I was trying to fix a memory leak issue but when I take heap snapshot or check real time allocation in Chrome DevTools, the page crashes with a "Aw, Snap!" message with error code STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION.

I am using Chrome Version 94.0.4606.61 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: https://crbug.com is where you should report Chrome bugs (don't hesitate to provide as much information as you can in your report, for instance a public link to the page where you are experiencing the issue will help them a lot).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this bug too. Workaround is to use incognito window for degugging.

---

update:
Version 95.0.4638.54 has fixed this issue. But in case similar issue come out again, you can always try to avoid it in incognito window.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked for me for some reason. I wonder what’s going on with Chrome profiles that it’s crashing the memory panel.

Comment: seems to be fixed for me in latest update

Comment: yep, version 95.0.4638.54 has fixed this.